# How to modify color in Hyperref package in jcappub package?

Tags: hyperref, color, templates

How to change color in `hyperref package while using [jcappub](https://jcap.sissa.it/jcap/help/JCAP/TeXclass/DOCS/jcappub.sty) environment? I tried in the following way -

```
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
         linkcolor = red,
         urlcolor  = magenta,
         citecolor = green,
         anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
```

It is not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be getting option-conflict warning messages, as the `hyperref` package is already loaded by the `jcappub` style file with the option (essentially) `allcolors=blue`. Don't ignore such messages. Please post a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that shows what exactly "is not working". Incidentally, where or how are `shilamagenta` and `shilagreen` defined?

Comment: I edited the question. Now I think there is no confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages can only be loaded once. But most of the `hyperref` configuration can also be handled via

```
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true,
  linkcolor = red,
  urlcolor  = magenta,
  citecolor = green,
  anchorcolor = blue
}
```

So just add your stuff there in your preamble (after loading `jcappub`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working.  I have used -
\hypersetup{citecolor=green,        
    linkcolor=red,  
    filecolor=magenta,     
    urlcolor=cyan  
}

BTW, can you please create a tag -'jcap' for all questions related to 'Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics', which a really popular research journal.

Comment: @PoreyS note that if you are forced to use the package for submitting an article, then it is not a good idea to change the layout including the colors of the links as then the editors would have to spend extra time undoing your changes

Comment: Ok. Thanks for this kind advice. I will try to change to their normal format just before submission.

Comment: BTW: if the answer solved your problem, click the check mark on it.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: @PoreyS There should be a check mark below the interface for voting on this question. It might only be visible when you hover. Or perhaps you don't have enough points yet